# Edge detection on photovoltaic modules on infrared images

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, edge-detection, canny-operator

**Context**

My goal is to detect PV modules on the dataset of infrared images taken by a drone. **I want to improve the edge detection** so my algorithm performs better. Detected and labelled modules are then used to train a neural network.

**Dataset**

I have several hundred images taken at different times and from different altitudes. I guess their quality is not perfect - the environmental conditions could be better, e.g:

*altitude* - sometimes the edges between modules are not the images could be taken from a lower altitude so the edges are better visible.

*capture time* - sometimes the background (grass) is very hot. Most likely the images could be taken late morning/early afternoon.

However, I have to stick to what I have.

[image: image_1]

[image: image_2]

[image: image_3]

As you can see sometimes (e.g. `image_3`) the "middle line" is hardly visible.

**Code**

Preprocessing below is based on project I found on Github. Standard preprocessing and Canny Edge detection is used.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def detect_edges():
    # image_path = "data/stackoverflow/TEMP_DJI_1_R (715).JPG"
    # image_path = "data/stackoverflow/TEMP_DJI_6_R (720).JPG"
    image_path = "data/stackoverflow/TEMP_DJI_5_R (657).JPG"

    # read image
    input_image = cv2.imread(image_path, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
    cv2.imshow('input_image', input_image)

    # scale image
    image_scaling = 11.0
    scaled_image_rgb = cv2.resize(src=input_image, dsize=(0, 0), fx=image_scaling, fy=image_scaling)
    cv2.imshow('scaled_image', scaled_image_rgb)

    # blur image
    gaussian_blur = 7
    blurred_image = cv2.blur(scaled_image_rgb, (gaussian_blur, gaussian_blur))
    cv2.imshow('blurred_image', blurred_image)

    # gray image
    grayed_image = cv2.cvtColor(scaled_image_rgb, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    cv2.imshow('grayed_image', grayed_image)

    # red threshold
    red_threshold = 120
    red_channel = scaled_image_rgb[:, :, 2]
    _, thresholded_image = cv2.threshold(red_channel, red_threshold, 255, 0, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

    # dilation and erosion
    kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (9, 9))
    closing = cv2.morphologyEx(thresholded_image, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
    opening = cv2.morphologyEx(closing, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)

    # min area
    min_area = 250 * 200
    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(opening, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    areas = [cv2.contourArea(contour) for contour in contours]
    discarded_contours = [area < min_area for area in areas]
    contours = [contours[i] for i in range(len(contours)) if not discarded_contours[i]]

    mask = np.zeros_like(grayed_image)
    cv2.drawContours(mask, contours, -1, (255), cv2.FILLED)

    mask = cv2.dilate(mask, kernel, iterations=5)
    mask = cv2.blur(mask, (25, 25))
    mask = mask.astype(np.float) / 255.
    preprocessed_image = (grayed_image * mask).astype(np.uint8)

    cv2.imshow('preprocessed_image', preprocessed_image)

    hysteresis_min_thresh = 25
    hysteresis_max_thresh = 40

    # canny edge
    canny_image = cv2.Canny(image=preprocessed_image, threshold1=hysteresis_min_thresh,
                            threshold2=hysteresis_max_thresh, apertureSize=3)
    cv2.imshow('canny_image', canny_image)
    cv2.waitKey()
```

**Results**

[image: res_1]

[image: res_2]

[image: res_3]

The results are not bad, however they must be improved before further processing.

What kind of operations would be best to distinguish panels from the background (grass)?

In the case of the images with hardly visible "middle" lines (`image_3`), are there any chances of finding that "internal" edge? Maybe for these images, I should rather focus on finding outer edges only and draw an artificial line in the middle to divide the whole panel into two?

Comment: FYI I'm running the same exact code and I'm not getting anything close to those results, this question is not answerable until we get reproducability

Comment: @Krupip I have used just exactly the same code with the images and for me works just fine. I needed only to change path to the files, and invoke function

Comment: Based on your input images and edge detection results, I believe if you downsize your images by a factor of 4 or 8, you may get better results which detects single-pixel width edges. Give it a try!

Comment: I'd recommend to stay away from Canny for this. beginners always use Canny for everything, even when it's nonsensical or counterproductive. post your source data in original raw grayscale, NOT false color. DO NOT convert false color to grayscale. false color has no brightness information. perhaps do a completely new question, ONLY show raw source data, and solicit approaches rather than asking people to fix your chosen approach, which may very well be wrong.